# Action Bar not updated when updating Locale

Tags: android, kotlin, locale

I want to update the Locale in my Android project as described [in this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages).

Everything works except that the action bar is not updated when the Locale is changed.

This is my code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    binding.mainBtnEnglish.setOnClickListener {
        setNewLocale("en")
    }
    binding.mainBtnArabic.setOnClickListener {
        setNewLocale("ar")
    }
}
private fun setNewLocale(tags: String) {
    val appLocale = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(tags)
    AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the action bar, you need to recreate the activity after setting the new locale.

To do this, just call **`recreate()`** after setting up the new locale:

```kotlin
private fun setNewLocale(tags: String) {
    val appLocale = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(tags)
    AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale)
    recreate()
}
```

The idea is to re-run the app so the next time when action bar is drawn; it will take the new locale in mind.

I hope this helps!